# .htaccess rewrite query request failed

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm having some troubles redirecting some particular urls.
I've got few urls like this: "/blog/?p=51"

My intent is to move from that link to "/blogs"

I've tried removing the query string using this code:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/blog/$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blogs [R=302,L]
```

Any advice?

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Paste your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: `/blogs/%` - what’s the percent sign supposed to achieve? If you want to refer to a grouped match from an earlier condition, then you need to include the “number” of the group, like so `%1`

Comment: I was referring to this guide https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: Do you see that guide using `%` on its own in the substitution part anywhere? It even explicitly mentions how this works already, _“As you can see, the value for the id parameter captured by the last RewriteCond is referenced in the target with the `%N` token where `N` is the number of the match in the regular expression.”_